# consuming kafka topic using spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have remote kafka server with 3 nodes and 1 zookeeper node.Also i have a HDP enabled cluster in which i have spark and other components running.
I created a sample topic in Kafka and tried to consume via Spark when i do that i always run in error.

1. When i do a spark submit for the first time i know my spark consumer is establishing connection and showing me the result of the topic.

2.When i do a spark-submit second time i get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker.

3. When i restart my kafka server again and do spark submit the code works fine and again if i do it then getting error again as above.

Anyone had an issue like this? as i dont know what is the mistake here.
Also i changed many versions in library dependencies and the error keeps coming.Below is my library dependency:

```
name := "consumers"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.3"
libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.3"
```

Tried all versions of spark and kafka but getting the same above error.

Comment: `"1.6.3"` must be `2.2.0`... All Spark versions must be the same and `2.10` must be `2.11`

Comment: tried that too but getting the same error

Comment: Please add your Spark code to the question

Comment: Also, if you are running HDP and you only have Spark 1.6.3, then you cannot use Spark 2.2.0 features anyway if it isn't installed

Comment: Might want to see https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_spark-component-guide/content/spark-choose-version.html

Comment: But even with 1.6.3 i am getting the same error.Can i degrade and use the spark streaming kafka versions for the same and check

Comment: And i checked the HDP it is said abt spark1 and spark2 and default spark1 is used for me